# Is using STM32 Blue Pill's TIM1 PWM under Arduino a problem?

Tags: stm32, pwm, stm32f103

I have a question about the use of TIM1 on the STM32 Blue Pill. I want to build a synchronous buck converter using the Blue Pill and need to use PWM on TIM1 ch1..3 together with their complementary outputs and programmable dead time.

I heard someone saying that using TIM1 for PWM was not a good idea. The Blue Pill has these function only on TIM1 ch1..3 so what can be the reason that using TIM1 for PWM is not a good idea?

I don't use HALL but program with Arduino and Bare Metal. Is TIM1 used for another function under Arduino?

Answer (score 0):

TIM1 is used by the servo routines in Arduino, according to https://www.robotshop.com/community/forum/t/arduino-101-timers-and-interrupts/13072

I can't vouch for whether that is true, or whether the same timers are used for the same things on every platform.

My own opinion is that the Arduino IDE makes many things easy, by hiding all the details, but when you need to know those details, or do stuff that's more under-the-hood, the environment complicates things.

Comment: Thanks for you input that means to me no problem then since I'm not planning to use servo libraries. Anyone else with ideas why that can be a problem.